# MVC Register and Login Model-- how many?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a created a "Register new user form" , and this use the following Model:

```
namespace FREELANCER.Models
{
    [Bind(Exclude = "UserID")]
    public class UserModel
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int UserID{ get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Fornavn")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Skriv venligst dit fornavn", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [RegularExpression(@"(^[a-zA-Z æøåÆØÅ]{0,25}$)", ErrorMessage = "Fornavn skal bestå af 2-25 bogstaver")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Efternavn")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Skriv venligst dit efternavn", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [RegularExpression(@"(^[a-zA-Z æøåÆØÅ]{0,25}$)", ErrorMessage = "Efternavn skal bestå af 2-25 bogstaver.")]
        public string LastName{ get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Telefonnummer")]
        [RegularExpression("(^[0-9]{8}$)", ErrorMessage = "Telefon skal bestå af 8 tal.")]
        public string Phone{get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kodeord")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Skriv venligst et kodeord", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(8, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Kodeordet skal mindst bestå af 4-8 karakter.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "E-mailadresse")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Skriv venligst din e-mailadresse", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Ugyldig e-mailadresse")]
        [Remote("DoUserExist","Home",ErrorMessage = "E-mail already in use")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Emailaddress{ get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "By")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vælg en by", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public int CityID { get; set; }

        public int EmailID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nyhedsbrev")]
        public bool SubscribeToNewsletter{ get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime UserCreated{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now I want to make a Login form , which must be:

Textbox (email address)
Textbox ( Password )
Subtmit_button

Should I make a New Model to it or use UserModel ?

```
public class LoginModel
{
public string Emailadress {get ; set ;}
public string Password {get ; set ;}
}
```

MVC Model concepts confuse my alot , plz help !

Comment: You have to use new model because if you use same user model than model valid return false because fields are required in user model

Comment: If you using many required fields on a base model, just create another model specifically using fields that required for login form. On your login form controller, push your data into base model and process its data on underlying database.

Comment: Thanks, How can i close this topic:
I accept your anwser, Tetsuya Yamamoto

Answer (score 0):

You should have to models for this work:
1)one for mapping to database table
2)one for your views

use your UserModel class to generating database table if you're using EF, or if you are using ADO.net use this table to do CRUD operations, and create another UserViewModel, UserViewModel class should only contain fields that you need in your View.

In your BL layer you can implement any codes to mapping objects of UserModel and UserViewModel based on your requirements.

Comment: I dont think OP is asking whether this class should be treated as domain model or entity.

Comment: you are right I just want to give a bit more information about it.